# Notification for Disk-Space Shortage Issue in Server

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, disk-space-utilization

I have a ubuntu server, and facing frequent space issue, i.e. logs are eating up lot of disk space. So, I want a check to be applied, so that whenever there is less than 5 GB free disk space, I should get an e-mail notification, so that I can delete the logs. How can I configure this. Do I need any other application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Ubuntu server, I have the following script in `/etc/cron.daily` that alerts me by email whenever `/dev/sdc` (my `/srv` partition) has less than 200MB of free space.

```
ALERT=200
UNIT=M
PARTITION=/dev/sdc

df -B$UNIT | grep "^$PARTITION" |
while read partition size used free perc mnt ;
do
        free_space=$(echo $free | tr -d $UNIT )
        if [ $free_space -le $ALERT ]; then
                echo "Partition $partition ($mnt) running out of space ($free) on $(hostname) as on $(date)" |
                mail -s "Alert: $mnt almost out of disk space on $(hostname) - $free" root
        fi
done
```

It was initially [taken and adapted from this blog post on nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html). Save this into a file in `/etc/cron.hourly` as root, modify the first 3 lines to suit your server and needs, and make the file executable. If you want to have it executed more often, save it as a script and create a regular cron job.

Note that you will need something providing the `mail` command, typically from the packages `qmail-run` or `courier-mta`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) for monitoring and sending email. But, before setting up monitoring, I would start by setting up [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to periodically rotate log files.

The appropriate system depends on where you host your server. For example, if it is hosted on AWS, you can configure Amazon's built-in [CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html) to monitor its health rather than deploy a new monitoring solution.

Comment: +1 for not only answering the nominal question, but also employing logrotate to avoid the need to manually intervene in the first place.

Comment: What Monty Harder said.

Answer (score 3):

You can adopt two different strategies:

- use a custom script which will run every minute/hour/day to detect and notify you about the space shortage
- install and deploy a true monitoring solution as [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) or the likes.

For a single server, solution n.1 is surely the faster path. However, for multiple servers and/or to check multiple data point (eg: ram usage, cpu load, etc) the second one is preferable, by far.

Answer (score 0):

Can some one help me out with my below concern?
Issue : need to setup one automatic job to perform disc space clear on Linux machine but the job which we create should be outside the Linux machine , so once we trigger that job the space in that Linux machine needs to be get cleared
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/504921)

Comment: This is another question, not an answer.